# GWT JsonpRequest pending

Tags: gwt

JsonpRequest misses isPending method, present at Request class. How can I check a JsonpRequest is pending? Is it bad to call cancel not knowing the JsonpRequest has finished or not? I mean, how harmful is cancelling an already canceled or completed JsonpRequest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been reported previously:

https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4867

You can follow the workaround explained in the issue (try/catch). I think there is no problem for your application cancelling a JsonpRequest (according to the issue worst scenario is an exception in browser).

Related with controlling exceptions, you might find useful this:

https://plus.google.com/+GoktugGokdogan/posts/4pwXTuzFS5x

Comment: Anyway, I need to try a couple of things, because maybe we can keep in some way a reference to the AsyncCall (globally), and inside of onFailue/onSuccess methods using "this" we can check if the response is the expected one.